# Impedance calculators differ pretty much?

Tags: tools, microstrip, calculator, waveguide

[image]

As you can see here to calculators I found show huge difference or didn't I set it up correctly? I didn't found hints on possible validity limits. Can someone say if one of those given out results is correct? I mean a mismatch of 18 ohm is a no go... Both freeware, is there a commercial software with higher quality?

Edit: Added image with **changed material, no significant change**, as to my knowledge only the dielectric constant is important, which was set to same value in first 2 pictures. Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: They are set to different materials, which probably affects the results.

Comment: As Brian said, make sure all the relevant specs are matched. Otherwise I can tell you that I've used TXLINE and it's very good. I've simulated and created physical boards and the numbers it gives are good.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I changed the material, but in TXLine it seems it is only important what you edit in the dielectric constant field, the "material" tab just saves this numbers for a few materials

Comment: @BrianDrummond I dont know why ur comment gets more upvotes, I changed the material and it didnt improve, what am I missing? Can you explain, thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind this : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48867/how-to-specify-100-ohm-impedance-on-a-pcb-gerber/48908#48908

Comment: @JamesLast Have you tried a loss tangent of 0?

Comment: @Kortuk yeah, I played a lot around with the parameters to see how much impedance varies at all, loss tangent only changes the impedance in decimals, either the AppCAD software is poor or I'm the donk

Comment: @Blup1980 thanks, so you think the AppCAD algorithm is just poor. But it seems like a change off the additional parameters in TXline doesnt change the impedance much compared to AppCAD, so I'm really wondering where this huge difference arises, 16 Ohm is a bad joke :)

Comment: @JamesLast this is operating in the "design equation" realm. The proper solutions for a design like this will often be iterative where it adjusts the design and analyzes the structure. The shape of the traces is being treated as a rectangle you can see, just adjusting for the fact that your trace is sloped on the edges really matters. You should fabricate it and measure it and see which one guessed right.

Comment: @JamesLast the reason I can tell you there is this variance very quickly. The two different simulations have a much different amount of the wave constrained in the substrate. Your top design thinks epsilon effective is 6.35 while the bottom software thinks it is 10.9. 10.9 seems a little too high to me, while 6.3 is a little above half of the wave is on the bottom half. If your pices where sloped down to match the bottom the way a real etched trace would be it would be higher than 6. There is a lot of messiness here, while a ground plane is more simplistic to design for.

Comment: I am not sure what program to use to draw the pictures I need to explain this.

Comment: @Kortuk you mean this kind of profiles after lift-off http://nanolithography.spiedigitallibrary.org/data/Journals/MOEMS/20343/001701jmm2.png or really a slope between signal and ground lines?